# IIS Express won't download .coffee files

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I just enabled source maps because, sure why not, I'd like to try them out. However, I'm finding that IISExpress will not download .coffee files so it doesn't work.

I'm sure it's a simple web.config modification, I'm just not sure which one. How do I configure it to serve these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of IIS Express's configuration is done through the configuration files; in this case you want

```
C:\Users\[user]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

In that file, there's a list of all of the static content types that IIS Express knows about and is willing to serve. You just need to add your extension to that list. The list starts about 1/2 down the file, in this XML element:

```
<staticContent lockAttributes="isDocFooterFileName">
```

It should be pretty obvious what to do from there: just map`.coffee` files to the correct mime type.

```
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".coffee" mimeType="text/plain" />
```

This element is found within the [`system.webServer`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver) element, which is one of the ones that supports delegation to individual `web.config` files, so you should be able to add a similar XML block to your project's configuration file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".coffee" mimeType="text/plain" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can I not add this somewhere in my project so that it works out of the box without every dev having to configure this?

Comment: I believe so; it's inside the `<system.webserver>` element, which you can delegate to child configuration files. I haven't tried but I'll explain how it "should" work.

Comment: Ah yes, that pointed me in the right direction. https://support.gearhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/200342605-Adding-Custom-MIME-types-to-your-site

Comment: BTW: an excellent reference for what can and cannot go into web.config: http://www.iis.net/configreference